# can't create directory SD card android rigth permissions

Tags: android, directory, android-permissions

maybe in 33 target the write permissions of the Sd card have changed
I am writing
`File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Temp"); if (!directory.exists()) { directory.mkdirs(); }`
does not create directory, error creating

while in the manifest there are read write  permissions external storage
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Please help me how to create directory
and create file android
compileSdk 33

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.export.exportcontacts"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
```

Comment: The function getExternalStorageDirectory has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card. Please rewrite your post to make clear what you want.

Comment: if(!directory.mkdirs()) return.